# Circle is inscribed in isosceles triangle with area $2$. Find angles of triangle for which radius of circle is maximal.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, optimization

> Circle is inscribed in isosceles triangle with area $2$. Find angles of triangle for which radius of circle is maximal.

I have $\displaystyle r=\frac{4}{\frac{4}{\sqrt{\sin x}}+\sqrt{\frac{8}{\sin x}-\frac{8\cos x}{\sin x}}}$ but I think this function doesn't lead to any.

Comment: What does "Circle is inscribed in isosceles triangle with Square 2" mean?

Comment: What is x? can you give a picture?

Comment: x is angle between equal sides of triangle. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick picture:

[image]

We can consider just half the isosceles triangle, as shown. Let the base be $b$ and height be $h$. The length of the base of half the triangle is $b/2$. The radius of the incircle is $b/2 \tan \theta/2$. The area of the whole isosceles triangle is $hb = b^2/4\tan\theta = 2$.

Using the double-angle formula for tangent,
$$ hb = \frac{b^2}{4}\frac{2\tan\theta/2}{1-\tan^2 \theta/2} = \frac{b^2}{4}\frac{2x}{1-x^2} = 2 $$
where $x = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$.
The above equation is a constraint on the base $b$ for a given $x$.

The radius is then
$$ r = b/2 \tan \theta/2 = \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{x}}x $$
Maximizing this, we set the derivative equal to zero, giving $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$, so $\theta/2 = \frac{\pi}{6}$, and so the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: Did you draw that in Paint?

Comment: Yep. It's quick and easy.